# Are pipelines capable of cacheing intermediate results?

Tags: scikit-learn, pandas, feature-extraction

I use pandas to do feature extraction for machine learning.
I hope to achieve the following: Consider I have five data processing steps done sequentially, and if I execute them once, the results will be saved automatically. Next time, if I change e.g. the fourth step, the library will automatically start from third step. Would this cache function be supported in pandas or `sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline` or other data processing libraries naturally without our need to save them explicitly?

Comment: I encountered the same inconvenience and created what is hopefully a useful library: [slobad](https://gitlab.com/slobad/slobad/)